# If $f(x)=x^{-n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, induction

If $f(x)=x^{-n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$  then  prove

$f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^{k} \frac{(n+k-1)!}{(k-1)!}$ $x^{-n-k} $

Of course I'm taking it by induction, but the main issue comes when  $k+1$  and my final result comes to this

I derive $f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^{k} \frac{(n+k-1)!}{(k-1)!}$ $x^{-n-k} $  therefore

$f^{(k+1)}(x)=(-1)^{k} \frac{(n+k-1)!}{(k-1)!}$ $x^{-n-k-1}(-n-k) =$

$f^{(k+1)}(x)=(-1)^{k+1} \frac{(n+k)!}{(k-1)!}$ $x^{-n-k-1}$

but my intuition tells me that I should get to

$f^{(k+1)}(x)=(-1)^{k+1} \frac{(n+k)!}{k!}$ $x^{-n-k-1}$

Any advice?

Comment: Do you mean to write $\color{blue}{(-1)}$'s instead of $\color{red}{-(1)}$, i.e. have the minus sign inside the brackets?

Comment: yes it was a finger mistake

Comment: Anyway, there looks to be a mistake in your formula (in the denominator). Consider the first few derivatives: $$\begin{align*}k=1&\Rightarrow -nx^{-n-1}, \\ k=2&\Rightarrow n(n+1)x^{-n-2}, \\ k=3&\Rightarrow -n(n+1)(n+2)x^{-n-3}.\end{align*}$$ In particular, note the coefficient (ignoring the sign) should be $n(n+1)\ldots (n+k-1)$. Can you write this using factorials?

Comment: When you take the derivative of a function, the correct verb is "differentiate", not "derive".

Comment: I will keep it in mind, english is not my native language

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the derivative has a typo in the denominator. It should be $(n-1)!$ instead of $(k-1)!$:
$$
f^{(k)}(x)=(−1)^k \frac{(n+k−1)!}{(n−1)!} x^{−(n−k)} .
$$

Using this expression, the proof by induction should work.

Comment: I don't believe you're mistaken since I came to the same conclusion that you did. Also, I agree the proof by induction will then work properly.